# How to send/receive parameters when using PostgreSQL NOTIFY with Java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm using J2EE and my code is below

```
public class Notifier {

    private Connection conn;

    public void notifyThread() throws SQLException {
      conn  =   ConnectionManager.getConnection();
      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
      stmt.execute("NOTIFY notificationRecived");
      stmt.close();
    }
}
```

At the listener's end I'm using:

```
org.postgresql.PGNotification notifications[] = pgconn.getNotifications();
```

To extract the details of notification. Here I noticed that

```
notifications[i].getParameter();
```

Is a method to extract the data which is sent along with the `NOTIFY` statement.
I saw few threads which suggest that we can pass data along with the `NOTIFY` statement like `NOTIFY notificationRecived, "xyz"`
but this one throws an error at `,xyz`.

Is there any other syntax to pass parameters along with `NOTIFY`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated code

```
public void notifyThread() throws SQLException {
  conn    =   ConnectionManager.getConnection();
  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.execute("SELECT pg_notify('notificationRecived', 'xyz');");
  stmt.close();    
}
```

To send a notification you can also use the function [`pg_notify(text, text)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html). The function takes the channel name as the first argument and the payload as the second. The function is much easier to use than the `NOTIFY` command if you need to work with non-constant channel names and payloads.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void notifyThread() throws SQLException {
  conn  =   ConnectionManager.getConnection();
  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

  stmt.execute("NOTIFY notificationRecived, 'xyz'");

  stmt.close();
}
```

According to documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html